# Is there a function in C that can take the largest integral value of a variable?

Tags: c

I made a program that can get the largest integral of a float value:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float get_value(float a);

int main() {
    float num = 4.58;
    float new_val = get_value(num);
    printf("%f \n", new_val);
}

float get_value(float a) {
    int c = a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
        a -= 0.01;
        if (a == c) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

It didn't work in the way I wanted it to be, so I want a shorthand of it instead of making a function.

So is there a function that I can use for this?

Comment: This doesn't work the way you think it should because [floating point math is weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Okay, I guess that makes sense. @Gereon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `floor()` if you want the lowest integer (closest to minus infinity) not exceeding the floating point value. Or use `trunc()` to get the smallest integer (closest to zero) not exceeding the magnitude of the fp value.

Also, note that .1 has a repeating representation in binary fp, so your function as written is always going to have problems. Just like 1/3 becomes .3333 in decimal.

Comment: That's the function I need. The `floor()` gave me 4.00, which is the result I'm looking for, and `trunc()` gave me the same thing.

Comment: @IPlayGamesBro  What do you want for negative values?

Comment: I just need to get the smallest average of a float, then use it for other operations. @stark

Answer (score 1):

You can use `modf`:

```
double integral, fractional;
double num = 4.58;
int result;

fractional = modf(num, &integral);
result = (int)integral;
```

Comment: The result is 04. I use C99.